# URL link for the project reports for the PNG

Tags: rally

Is there a way using a REST API or some other means to get the end point the URL which holds PNG for the iteration break down, velocity chart, iteration cumulative flow diagram for each project so that we can share it across.

Something like below

https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/analytics/report/view/3161993978732214d/chart.png

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to share it?  If you'd like to embed it in a wiki or sharepoint it's fairly easy to embed a custom app with that chart in it.  The generated report images themselves are not actually linkable- they are generated as a client side image map...

Comment: thank you for the response. i am trying to post it as the URL to the hipchat room.